# CSS target class names starting with before a certain character

Tags: css

I have a number of class names which I need to change.

Right now the class name is just .col

so I have some css that looks like this:

```
.col {width:50%};
```

Now... I have some classes that look like this:

```
.one-col {something here};
.two-col {something here};
```

How can I change .col {};  so that it targets any of the ones that look like the above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use partial selector * like this:

```css
[class*="col"]{
  height: 50px;
  background: #333;
}
.one-col {
  background: blue;
}
.two-col {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="asas-col-asadas"></div>
<div class="one-col"></div>
<div class="two-col"></div>
```

Check this out fore mere info https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/

Comment: Just a heads up that this will also match ie. `acolade` (*so any class that contains `col` in its name at any position*)

Comment: Yes you'r right, `*` select the class contains the value somewhere in it , in your case you can use a more specific substring like [class*= "-col"] or if your classes were so `.col-one` you would use `[class|= "col"]` this select the class starts with "col" in a dash-separated list

Answer (score 2):

Use the contains selector

```
[class*="-col"] {width:50%};
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add both classes to the elements you want so that would inherit the properties from both classes.

```
<div class="col one-col">...</div>
```

---

Alternatively (*although looks like a bad idea, as it relies on the order the classes are applied to the element*) would be the **ends-with** attribute selector.

```
[class $= "-col"] {width:50%}
```